# LinkedIn API V2 - How to get connections (already using my app) of a member using member access token

Tags: linkedin-api

After the new API V2 updates, member his access token to get connections who are also using my app requires a permission `r_network` or `r_compliance`

After some search, found some recommendations to enroll to partnership with linked in which were one of three options (**Talent**, **Marketing** or **Sales**) which i read the description of them and did not know which one should we apply for.

The question is, how do i obtain the required permissions to get member connections?

Comment: i have the exact same question!